# How to embed text over video using ffmpeg library

Tags: android

I am trying to use the FFmpeg library, but not able to  Successfully. If there any example which I can refer please help me. I am facing this problem for last 3 days.thanks in advance.I am trying some command, but it always shows me error " CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE ffmpeg: has text relocations" .

Comment: what's your exact requirement ?

Comment: add what you tried , and add what is your expected output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sir i want add text over video thats my cmd       String command[]={"ffmpeg","-i","/sdcard/video.mp4","-vf", "drawtext="+"\""+"fontfile=/sdcard/retro.ttf: text='Test Text'"+"\"",output};

Comment: i tried 2 things 1 image over video and 2 text over video both time i getting ffmpeg invalid argument        String addimgcmd[]={"-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a copy",output};